# android GCM example, error when send message from server

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm following the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html#server-setup. I use webserver (it's a free jsp server on the web, not localhost). Everything was fine, my device was registered successfully to the server, on the page it said 1 devices is registered. However, when I click the send message, the error below pop up. I wonder it's the server I used prevented some method (so that I switch server), or the example code provided by Google has a loophole? tks.

Sorry the exception report is lengthy (but don't know what is needed)

```
Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission android.googleapis.com:443 connect,resolve)
    java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1034)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:271)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:328)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:793)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:896)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:468)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:447)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:170)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
    com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:76)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.23 logs.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have pasted the correct API key into the app. Try using the "Browser" API key instead of the "Server" API key.

Comment: Yes I did, and my device was only be registered after I used the Browser API key. So that's not the cause

Comment: You'll probably have to pull the full stack trace out of the Tomcat error logs.

Comment: cant post here (character limit) pls see https://docs.google.com/document/d/11jjmwYRIidYWDh_aQJNzyiNP4svbtewQw22LNcSE9Q4/edit